Custom Action Buttons on Form in Laravel Nova 4
I am trying to create a custom button at the bottom of a resource that will save the record and then take all of the information in that record and duplicate it into another record.

This duplicated/copied information would then give the user a jumpstart to enter another record. Right now the only actions on the Create and Update pages are Create/Update, Create/Update and Add Another but those two buttons don't fit all circumstances. And the last option just provides a blank form. I want the previously entered information to be auto-added to the form to save time.
And I am aware of the replicate function. But this requires the record to be saved and the user to return to the record and then select the replicate option. When I have users entering hundreds of items at a time, this extra step is very time consuming.
Can somebody help me figure out a way to add additional buttons to the forms so that I can extend the create and update functionality?

What have you tried so far?

@SimonC I've tried very little honestly because I cannot find any documentation on how to manipulate this area of Nova.

If you need a quick solution to pre-hydrate the form fields for a new resource with the same values as the last resource created, you could try something like:


public function fields(NovaRequest $request) {

    $latestResource = null;
    if ($request->isCreateOrAttachRequest()) {
        $latestResource = Account::latest('id')->first();
    }

    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),

        Text::make(__('First Name'), 'first_name')
            ->withMeta([
                'value' => $latestResource ? $latestResource->first_name : $this->first_name
            ]),

        Text::make(__('Last Name'), 'last_name')
            ->withMeta([
                'value' => $latestResource ? $latestResource->last_name ??  $this->last_name
            ]),
     ];
}


This is a curious approach, but the client doesn't always want to perform this function. Sometimes they want a Save and New (which the out-of-the-box functionality facilities) and other times they want a Save and Replicate. I'm amazed there isn't a simple way to just add an additional button to the buttons at the bottom of the form.
